# MYSQL join subquery using count(*) to find the number of relationships a user has

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a table named users which has fields id, email, username, firstname, and lastname.

I have another table named friends which has fields id, user1, user2, and relationship.

I am having a really hard time with this join query that shouldn't be so hard :(.

I want to find the most popular users that are not already related to you. For example, I have a relationship array already generated and I want to find the user info and the amount of relationships they have that are users not already related to you.

Here is my query so far, but I can't get it to work for some reason.

```
select id, email,username,firstname,lastname
from users as userInformation
     left join (select count(*)
                from friends
                where friends.user1 = userInformation.id or friends.user2 = userInformation.id
               ) as x
where users.id NOT IN (2,44,26,33,1)
```

the "2,44,26,33,1" in the `not in` part is arbitrary depending on the logged in user.
the part that I can't get working properly is the left join which adds the relationship count.

Just to help out, here are the two queries that work. I just need to join the second one to be a column on the first query for each user

```
 select id, email,username,firstname,lastname from users where id NOT IN (2,44,26,33,1)

 select count(*) from friends where user1 =2 or user2 = 2
```

But the second query should be for each id in the first query.  hope that clears it up.

This is getting closer

```
select id, email,username,firstname,lastname 
  from users as help
  left join (
      select count(*) 
        from friends 
       where user1 = help.id or user2 = help.id) as friendCounter
 where help.id NOT IN (2,44,26,33,1)
```

For some reason it wont recognize help.id in the where clause in the end.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Is relationship commutative?  That is, are there rows in friends for A related to B and another for B related to A.

Comment: the user ids are relational, so the user1 and user2 information in the friends table is the same as the id field in the users table

Comment: so an example could be in the users table 2 records: id = 1, email = danny@test.com, username = danny, firstname = danny, lastname = test; next record id = 2, email = brian@test.com, username = brianyeah, firstname = brian, lastname = whatever.  then in the friends table if they are friends then there will be a record like this id=1234 user1 = 1, user2 = 2

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have edited your question text to increase its formality and presentation. SO is an archival question-and-answer system, so it makes sense to take some care with your presentation.  Who knows? In five years a potential employer or co-worker may look up your contributions here.

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout this?

```
select userinformation.id, email,username,firstname,lastname,count(*)
from users as userInformation
     left join  friends on friends.user1 = userInformation.id or friends.user2 = userInformation.id

where userInformation.id NOT IN (2,44,26,33,1)
group by email,username,firstname,lastname
```

Comment: thank you for your help, i tried your solution and it said "column 'id' in field list ambiguous

Comment: If that column appears in both tables, you need to qualify it. MySQL needs to know which table you want to use. Change id to userInformation.id

Comment: Missed that. Should teach me to write sql without testing it.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
    select id, email,username,firstname,lastname,count(*) N
        from users as userInformation
             left join  friends on friends.user1 = userInformation.id 
                                   or friends.user2 = userInformation.id

        where userInformation.id NOT IN (2,44,26,33,1)
        group by id,email,username,firstname,lastname) Aliased
order by N desc
```

Comment: why select all from a subquery and then sort it, insted of just sorting it?

Comment: I wasn't sure all databases allow "order by count(*)". do they?

Comment: the question was about mysql, and mysql allows it, don't know about the others, but thanks for clearing out why :-)

Comment: i tried your solution and it says "every derived table must have its own alias"

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to re-phrase your problem statement as I understand it. Let me know if it's wrong.

For a given user, find most popular unrelated users:

```
declare @GivenUser as varchar(20)
set @GivenUser = '1'  --replace '1' here with the user id you want

select id, email, username, firstname, lastname, Connections
from userInformation u1
inner join (
    select TheUser, count(*) as Connections
    from (
        select user1 as TheUser
        from friends
        where user1 <> @GivenUser
        and user2 <> @GivenUser

        union all

        select user2 as TheUser
        from friends
        where user1 <> @GivenUser
        and user2 <> @GivenUser
        ) u
    group by User
    order by sum(Connections) desc
    ) u2
on u1.id = u2.TheUser
```

Comment: im sorry for not explaining correctly.  pretty much a user logs in and i would like to show this user the most popular users to be friends with.  the most popular users simply have the highest count of records in the friends table. hope that helps

Comment: select id, email,username,firstname,lastname from users as help
left join (select count(*) from friends where user1 = help.id or user2 = help.id) as friendCounter
where help.id NOT IN (2,44,26,33,1) this is close, just need it to link up the id from the first part to the id in the NOT IN clause

Comment: This query would do that exactly that: display the most popular users that the logged-in user is not already friends with. As for linking up the two ids in your query, I tried to figure out a way to do that -- unsuccessfully.